# Dual booting older (2011) MBP into Windows and Linux (not macOS)

Tags: windows, startup, unix, dual-boot

I was given a 8,2 15" MBP, and b/c its graphics won't allow me to install Mojave, I want to turn it into a dual booted Linux/Windows machine. (I'm a developer, and find myself needing to tread into both worlds more and more.)

I found [this article](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-triple-boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-5531037) to help with this... except I don't really need to keep a viable older macOS on this machine. Just Win7 (which I'm gonna quickly upgrade to Win10) and Ubuntu Desktop. How would you, after getting rEFInd installed, and Win/Linux installed, excise the macOS still there? Or is this even the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

I read your [this article](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-triple-boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-5531037). Follow the steps outlined in the article with these adjustments.  I'd set up three partitions instead of four: macOS, swap and Windows. I'd adjust the macOS partition to the size you want to for linux. I'd install linux over the top of the macOS partition.

I've set up a triple boot system before but I haven't tried this procedure. Good luck.